# Extend /home with additional 50GB

Tags: partition, lvm, home

I would like add additional space of 50GB either to existing hard disk or new disk, whichever fits well, but this space should be mounted at `/home`. My `sda2` is already mounted at `/home`. I am using RHEL.

```
$ df -h
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                63G     0   63G   0% /dev
tmpfs                   63G     0   63G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                   63G  3.4G   60G   6% /run
tmpfs                   63G     0   63G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/rhel-root  540G  196G  345G  37% /
/dev/mapper/rhel-var    12G  302M   12G   3% /var
/dev/mapper/rhel-home  2.0G   47M  2.0G   3% /home
/dev/sda6              7.0G   83M  7.0G   2% /tmp
/dev/sda7              7.0G  251M  6.8G   4% /var/log
/dev/sda9              7.0G   83M  7.0G   2% /var/tmp
/dev/sda8              7.0G   83M  7.0G   2% /var/log/audit
/dev/sda5               55G  4.7G   51G   9% /xyz
/dev/sda1              2.0G  184M  1.7G  11% /boot
/dev/sda3             1022M  4.0K 1022M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/loop4             318M  318M     0 100% /abc-os
```

```
$ fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 700 GiB, 751619276800 bytes, 1468006400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xe925ee1a
Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *          2048    4196351    4194304    2G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2          4196352 1270892543 1266696192  604G 8e Linux LVM
/dev/sda3       1270892544 1272989695    2097152    1G ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sda4       1272989696 1468006399  195016704   93G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1272991744 1388335103  115343360   55G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       1388337152 1403017215   14680064    7G 83 Linux
/dev/sda7       1403019264 1417699327   14680064    7G 83 Linux
/dev/sda8       1417701376 1432381439   14680064    7G 83 Linux
/dev/sda9       1432383488 1447063551   14680064    7G 83 Linux
```

```
$ lsblk
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop4           7:4    0  318M  1 loop /abc-os
sda             8:0    0  700G  0 disk
├─sda1          8:1    0    2G  0 part /boot
├─sda2          8:2    0  604G  0 part
│ ├─rhel-root 253:0    0  540G  0 lvm  /
│ ├─rhel-swap 253:1    0   50G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
│ ├─rhel-var  253:2    0   12G  0 lvm  /var
│ └─rhel-home 253:3    0    2G  0 lvm  /home
├─sda3          8:3    0    1G  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda4          8:4    0    1K  0 part
├─sda5          8:5    0   55G  0 part /xyz
├─sda6          8:6    0    7G  0 part /tmp
├─sda7          8:7    0    7G  0 part /var/log
├─sda8          8:8    0    7G  0 part /var/log/audit
└─sda9          8:9    0    7G  0 part /var/tmp
sr0            11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: is it possible you mixed up swap (50G) and home (2G) when setting this up? do you want swap 2G home 50G? your rootfs is also quite large (540G) where is this used if not in /home? difficult to give specific advice since it depends too much on your individual setup / personal preferences

Comment: @frostschutz,  i was able to add another disk and extend the Home